# How to change the parent working directory from which my executable is run?

Tags: shell, haskell, directory, optparse-applicative

My project is a command-line application in Haskell and uses the [opt-parse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative) applicative package to handle parsing of command line options.

I am trying to implement a functionality which can change the working directory of the shell from which the command was run.

For example, I want to do something like

```
$ program foo
```

and have the shell change to a specified directory my program has associated with the passed option `foo`.

```
$ program foo
input 'foo'; now changing to directory '~/mydirectories/foodirectory'
[~/mydirectories/foodirectory]$
```

I attempted to implement this functionality using the [`setCurrentDirectory`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/directory-1.3.1.5/docs/System-Directory.html#g:2) function from the `directory` package, however this does not appear to affect the working directory in the shell from which the directory is run; no change in the working directory appears. I am imagining that it is setting some kind of internal-to-the-program working directory, as I see no change in the shell from which the executable was run.

Is it possible to have my program change directories in this manner? Such directory-switching functionality would improve the convenience of using my application.

**How can I implement directory-switching functionality from a command-line executable?**

Comment: Not a shell limitation *or* a Haskell limitation -- you couldn't write a program in C that changed the directory of a separate C program that launched it, either, without the parent process's active participation, or using debugger interfaces or the like.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see, thanks. It seems that instead of changing directories I'll have to print out the path so the user can copy and `cd` to it. Out of curiosity, how does the `cd` program command work to change directories?

Comment: `cd` is not a separate program, it's a shell builtin. `/usr/bin/cd` may exist on your OS, but doesn't actually *work* to change directories in the shell that invokes it.

Comment: `cd` a shell builtin, alright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can't do this. No program can change its parent process's directory, no matter what language it's written in, using standard UNIX interfaces. A program can only change its own directory (and, by extension, the initial working directory of any programs it subsequently starts).

However, *with the shell's active participation*, you can make something very similar. Consider instructing your users to run a shell function such as the following:

```
# this wrapper works on any POSIX shell, but will avoid setting a global variable "dir" if
# the active shell (like bash, ksh, or even dash) supports local variables.
chdirWithMyHaskellProgram() {
    local dir 2>/dev/null || \
      declare dir 2>/dev/null || \
      : "current shell does not support local variables; proceeding anyhow"
    dir="$(myHaskellProgram "$@")" && cd -- "$dir"
}
```

...will cause `chdirWithMyHaskellProgram --foo-bar` to call `myHaskelProgram --foo-bar`, and change to the directory named in the output of same, if and only if the exit status indicates success.

---

Consider having `myHaskelProgram --eval` emit the source code to the above function. If you implemented this, then your user would need to put `eval "$(myHaskelProgram --eval)"` in their dotfiles, but would thereafter have the desired functionality.